# How do I increase the size of the .net core 2.1 file upload?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm stuck to the maximum limit of file upload in my .net core project. After adding the following code to program.cs, which is the limit of 25 mb as defult, I was able to do 120mb, but I can't exceed 120mb no matter what I do.

```
.UseKestrel (options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 2147483648; // 2GB
});
```

I also added the following code to web.config.

```
<Configuration>
 <System.webServer>
  <Security>
   <RequestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength = "2147483648" />
   </ RequestFiltering>
  </ Security>
 </System.webServer>
 <System.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength = "2147483648" executionTimeout = "1000000" />
 </System.web>
</ Configuration>
```

Comment: With a file bigger than 120mb, you have a error message? a log? or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Multipart forms to upload the file, then you should change the limit here:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
    x.ValueLengthLimit = 2147483648;
    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 2147483648;
    x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = 2147483648;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the attribute to your action directly?

```
[RequestSizeLimit(1024000)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
   // your code here
}
```